# Widget in Jupyter Notebook without a code

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook

We would like to build a system where the user can compose Jupyter Notebook with whatever logic she needs, but provide additional functionality based on our existing system. To access that additional functionality user will need some help coming from our software. User will use the UI which facilitates composing statements which access our system. For example, to let the user retrieve a variable stored in our system, we need to display list of variables, once user selected a variable - list of keys variable has, so the user could provide values for those keys.

We have been looking at NB Extensions in JavaScript and optionally Python backend. JavaScipt would request necessary information via REST, parse provided JSON and fill controls accordingly, no problem with that. However, the user would need to click a button on Toolbar to access that JavaScript dialogs.

We came across Widgets which are even more convenient than NB extensions. However, to place a Widget into Jupyter Notebook, user has to provide a code which imports ipywidgets library, creates a widget, populates it with data (speaking about dropdown selector, user would need to call REST service, parse JSON and populate dropdown with items from JSON) and inserts it into the Notebook.

Question - can we somehow combine power of NB extensions and Widgets? For example, provide template Jupyter Notebook with single widget saying "select command". Once user made a selection, set of widgets to help composing selected command appears, original "select command" widget disappears, and reappears as the last element in the notebook. No visible code in the notebook related to those widgets must present, all this "magic" must be delivered as some extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to create an nbextension that autofills the first cell of a notebook with a certain value. This value could theoretically be set to a set of python commands that imports the correct modules and inserts the widget code and then programmatically runs the cell, thus hiding the code and displaying the widget. Then, the widget code could do the bulk of the logic of performing the autofills the rest of the time.

Essentially, you use an nbextension to automatically populate and fill the first cell with the code for the widget and run said widget. Then you do the rest with widgets.

e.g.
Autopopulate cell with

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.IntSlider()
```

to get a slider in the cell.

```
define(function(){
    function load_ipython_extension(){
        //only perform on empty cell i.e. only on a new notebook
        if(Jupyter.notebook.get_cell(0).get_text() === "") {
            var first_cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_cell(0);
            first_cell.set_text("import ipywidgets as widgets\n    widgets.IntSlider()")
            first_cell.execute();
            first_cell.metadata["hide_input"] = true;
            first_cell.element.find("div.input").hide();
        }
    }

    return {
        load_ipython_extension: load_ipython_extension
    };
});
```

EDIT: It seems I misremembered about widgets hiding the code that ran them. Taking a look at how the [Hide Input nbextension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/blob/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/hide_input/main.js) does it, I've added some extra code to hide the input of the code cell.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it does not hide the cell which says: import  ipywidgets as widgets widgets.IntSlider()  The whole point of the question is to be able to see only output widgets, not the code cells which define their appearance and behavior.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I misremembered. I've updated my answer to hide the code cell input and just leave the widget. You might have to create some more logic in the nbextension to hide the inputs for the other widgets, as I'm not sure whether widgets can manipulate the notebook like nbextensions can.